# How to use Julia to find root (in 1-D case)

Tags: julia

Suppose I have the following problem

[image]

Make it simpler:

1. n=3
2. z1 = 1; z2 = 2; z3 = 3
3. \tau = 1
4. u is the variable in 1D.

Goal: solve f(u) = 0.

Note: Suppose I have to write the above in a function.

---

The following is my work: [image]

My questions are:

1. Does it look correct?
2. $u$ is the root, if I have no idea about my root priori, how could I do "max( )"?
3. Since I use fzero(), so I have to estimate the place of the root at first; otherwise, I have to give a range and use fzeros(f,a,b). Correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fzero` expects an univariate 1D function as its first argument and an initial guess as the second. The way you define `f(u)` and pass it to `fzero` is not correct: You define the constant function `f(u) = 0` and then overwrite that definition with new (recursive) definitions. You then pass the *value* `f(u)` instead of the *function* `f` to `fzero`.

What you probably wanted is the following:

```
using Roots
function findroot(z, tau)
    function f(u)
        res = 0
        for i = 1:3
            res += max(abs(z[i]) - u, 0)
        end
        res -= tau
        return res
    end
    fzero(f, 3)
end
```

First, the code above defines a function `f` (a closure) that depends on `z` and `tau` from the enclosing environment (the outer function `findroot`). Then, the function `f` and the initial guess are passed to `fzero`.

I prefer defining the function in the global scope and explicitly pass the parameter as arguments. A shorter implementation of your function is:

```
 f(u, z, tau) =  sum(max(abs(zi) - u, 0) for zi in z) - tau
```

This way, one can investigate its behavior, e.g., by plotting it for different parameters:

```
using Plots
plot(u->f(u, [0,1,2], 1), 0, 4)
```

The syntax `args -> body` defines an anonymous function. One can then define `findroot` using the same syntax:

```
findroot(z, tau) = fzero(u->f(u, z, tau), 0)
```